# Using OpenGL textures larger than window/display size

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm having problems using textures that are larger than the OpenGL window or the display size as non-display render targets.
What's the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simple solution.

Assuming your (non-display) textures are **1024x1024** and you are restricted to a **256x256** window/display.

```
unsigned int WIN_WIDTH = 256;
unsigned int WIN_HEIGHT = WIN_WIDTH;
unsigned int TEX_WIDTH = 1024;
unsigned int TEX_HEIGHT = TEX_WIDTH;
```

Use the *window size* to create your OpenGL window:

```
glutInitWindowSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
```

But, use the *texture size* for everything else:

```
glViewport(0, 0, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT);
gluOrtho2D(0.0, TEX_WIDTH, 0.0, TEX_HEIGHT);
glTexCoord2i(TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT);
```